# Getting time between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
Id  Start                End
1   2019-01-28 07:00:00  2019-01-28 17:00:00
2   2019-01-28 17:01:00  2019-01-28 02:00:00
```

What I want to do is to check when I run my query if current time is between times from id 1 or 2. This is my query.

```
SELECT Id FROM MyTableName 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108)
BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(5), Start, 108) AND
CONVERT(varchar(5), End, 108)
```

At the moment works fine if I run my query from hour 07 to 17 (Id 1) but when I try it after 17:01 query doesn’t show any result. Playing with my query I found that it’s because 02:00 hour (id 2, 02:00 means 2am).

How can I handle this?

Comment: 02:00 really means 2am. You should make the end time to be 2019-01-29 02:00:00.

Comment: @rcs The main problem is that on my table I would not have an start and end date time for all days. My table only going to containt that above two rows. If I do what you say query is going to work tomorrow, next week, next month, etc.?

Comment: No. Next month you will need to update the start and end date to be next month. There is no way now in Feb and your table content is still in Jan and you expect them to work.

Comment: `20190128 17:02` is not between `20190128 17:01 ` and `20190128 02:00`. The query does work as it will show no row in return. The problem is why you said the query doesn't work?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach You’re right, I edit my question so now I say that doesn’t show any result because I’m expecting that if I run my query at 8 pm query returns Id 2.

Comment: Could you explain the logic that make `2019-01-28 20:00` between `2019-01-28 17:00` and `2019-01-28 02:00`? Do you means `2019-01-29 02:00` or anything else?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Exactly! That’s what I want to do, if I run my query on 2019-02-01 at 8 pm I need to check if 8pm it’s between 2019-02-01 17:00 and 2019-02-02 02:00, but like I said above, I’m not able to insert data on my table for every day, I’m going to have only that data.

Comment: If your data is wrong, first you should find a logic to `fix` that data in all wrong cases. Something like `if  end < start then end = end + 1 day`. After having that logic, then you could go to next step - rewrite your query with that logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback you've given in the comments, I think the best way to achieve what you want is actually possible in a single query without using a table at all.

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (GETDATE() > SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 7, 00)) AND (GETDATE() < SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 17, 00)) THEN 1 
WHEN (GETDATE() > SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 4, 00)) AND (GETDATE() < SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE())+1, 2, 00)) THEN 2
ELSE NULL END AS ID
```

The above query will return ID 1 if the time is between 07:00 and 17:00, 2 if the time is between 17:00 and 02:00(the next day) and NULL if the time is outside of either of these windows.